# Force new files to have permissions 660 instead of 600?

Tags: chmod, acl, umask

There is a particular program that creates files and directories with permissions 600 and 700, respectively. It creates them within its own working directory, `/home/me/program`. I want those permissions to be 660 and 770 instead. The program is closed source, so changing it isn't an option. The umask is 002, so I know it isn't restricting the group permission. The program is simply specifying a restrictive permission on its own.

I considered setting a default ACLs, but it turns out that ACLs can only make a standard permission set more restrictive, not less.

I could probably react to file/dir creation events with inotifywait and issue chmod commands in response, but that feels kind of ugly.

I was hoping you guys would have a better way!

Comment: There is no way to coerce a program from the "outside" to create files using a prescribed `umask`. Poking the binary is probably your best hope.

Comment: `umask` can remove permissions that a program specifies to `creat` or equivalent but cannot add them. If your Unix supports ACLs, and the program doesn't set them, I think a default ACL on the directory can't grant access to the owning group but can to another group or other user(s) which might suffice for you. Whether that is less ugly I offer no opinion.

Comment: You haven't posted what your system's `umask` is set to, so the best way to proceed is impossible to know.  If, for example, your system's `umask` is set to `077`, setting it to `007` would do what you want - assuming the program doesn't set it's own `umask` or explicitly set the file and directory permissions.  To get a real "best answer", you need to provide a lot more information.

Comment: The umask is set to 002. As dave_thompson_085 pointed out, though, the umask can only remove permissions from the creat call. It can't add them.

I looked into ACLs as well. Default ACLs seemed like the perfect solution to my problem, until I discovered that they can only make the standard Linux permissions more restrictive. So for example, if the file's permissions are 777, an ACL can deny permissions for a named group. But if permissions are 700, ACLs can't grant those permissions. Too bad.

Answer (score 1):

A solution may be to set the permissions independently from outside the binary. Depending on context and requirements, you could either create a cron job calling a script, wrap the call to the binary along with subsequent cleanup code in a script or implement something more sophisticated using the [inotify(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) interface.